# Musing on Earth's gravity

Tags: tides, earth-moon

(a) What, if anything, is the difference between Earths geographic center, *i.e.* mid-point of the spin axis, and the gravitational center?

(b) What is the average distance between the Earth's center of gravity, and the Earth-Moon system's center of gravity?

(c) The recent 'super-moon' is a reminder that the moon's distance has an orbital wobble. So, by how much does this vary the distance between the Earth *vs* Earth-Moon gravitational centres, and

(d) Is the moon's varying distance from the Earth sufficient to create any noticeable effect upon sea/ocean tidal amplitudes?

Comment: PS: By 'noticeable', I mean more than a few millimeters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter

Comment: I think there's more than one question here. (c) and (d) are easy to relate and fit together (and FWIW, I'm pretty sure the answer to (d) is "yes"), but I think the others need asking separately. Might I suggest seperating them out?

Comment: Information on (d): http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8917/how-often-do-king-tides-perigean-spring-tides-occur

Comment: What exactly is the "mid-point of the spin axis"? The axis is infinitely long, it doesn't have a mid-point.

Answer (score 1):

For (a) through (c), consider the differences between the [geoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid) and the reference ellipsoid, in addition to the barycentre.

For (d): A slightly higher [perigean spring tide](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/perigean-spring-tide.html) than usual, meaning in some geographical locations perhaps an amplitude difference of inches rather than millimetres.